# Is it possible to add a serchable option to an existing custom spinner?

Tags: android, search, spinner

So basically the title says it. I am going to try and put the code in and it would be nice if i could get an answer.

SecondFragment.

```
override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_second, container, false)
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    view.findViewById<Button>(R.id.button_second).setOnClickListener {
        findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_SecondFragment_to_FirstFragment)




            }



    val spinner04 = view.findViewById<AppCompatSpinner>(R.id.spinner04)
    val modelList: List<Model> = readFromAsset()
    val customDropDownAdapter = CustomDropDownAdapter(requireContext(), modelList)
    spinner04.adapter = customDropDownAdapter

    }

private fun readFromAsset(): List<Model> {
    val file_name = "android_version.json"

    val bufferReader = requireActivity().application.assets.open(file_name).bufferedReader()

    val json_string = bufferReader.use {
        it.readText()
    }
    val gson = Gson()
    val modelList: List<Model> = gson.fromJson(json_string, Array<Model>::class.java).toList()
    return modelList
}
}
```

Spinner in fragmentsecond.xml

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatSpinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner04"
    android:layout_width="365dp"
    android:layout_height="69dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="292dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button_second"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.531"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="245dp"
    android:layout_height="31dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="172dp"
    android:text="Izaberite zemlju"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/spinner04"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.614"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.034" />
```

custom_spinner_item.xml

```
 <ImageView android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:id="@+id/img"
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"/>

<TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:paddingStart="10dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp" />
```

I can show the CustomAddapterCode as well if needed. The thing is i am tryng to implement a search option in the spinner but i hope that i don`t need to make a new spinner. So any suggestions?

[You can take a look what i would like is to place that option either at Izaberite zemlju or at the actual Spinner that`s how it looks.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IN9Hw.png)

CustomDropDownAdapter

```
private val inflater: LayoutInflater = context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater

override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup?): View {

    val view: View
    val vh: ItemHolder
    if (convertView == null) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_spinner_item, parent, false)
        vh = ItemHolder(view)
        view?.tag = vh
    } else {
        view = convertView
        vh = view.tag as ItemHolder
    }
    vh.label.text = dataSource.get(position).name

    val id = context.resources.getIdentifier(dataSource.get(position).url, "drawable", context.packageName)
    vh.img.setBackgroundResource(id)

    return view
}

override fun getItem(position: Int): Any? {
    return dataSource[position];
}

override fun getCount(): Int {
    return dataSource.size;
}

override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
    return position.toLong();
}

private class ItemHolder(row: View?) {
    val label: TextView
    val img: ImageView

    init {
        label = row?.findViewById(R.id.text) as TextView
        img = row?.findViewById(R.id.img) as ImageView
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Convert spinner as dialog with a list and implement a search with an adapter inside it

Comment: Any way you can send me a code for that if it`s convinient for you? If not i will try to google it tough.

Comment: Ive moded the spinner to be a dialog tell me am i supposed to put a search option within my existing CustomDropDownAdapter? Not sure if i can send the code from it here.

Comment: make the array as public the one you add inside the adapter and add to the dialog edit text now 
searchEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(final Editable editable) {
add here the method now filter the values based on  editable
if (locationModelArrayListMainItems.get(x).getName().toLowerCase().startsWith(editable.toString().toLowerCase())) {
then add to new list and apdate your adapter

Comment: Got to take a look at some examples not sure that i get it.